# What does the PC1 and PC2 stands for in LDAvis?

Tags: pca, lda, topic-modeling, pyldavis

I am new to LDA modelling and have managed to plot topics for some documents in LDAvis but noticed there is PCA 1 and PCA 2 on the axis of the plot, what are they and how can I find out what they are in my documents?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a named list used to customize various plot elements. By default, the x and y
axes are labeled "PC1" and "PC2" (principal components 1 and 2), since jsPCA
is the default scaling method.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LDAvis/LDAvis.pdf